# Angular: Issue while exporting to CSV, field with '-' value converting to date

Tags: angular, typescript

My code

```
import { ExportToCsv } from 'export-to-csv';
 
var data = [
  {
    name: 'Test 1',
    age: 13,
    average: 8.2,
    score: '3-1',
    approved: true,
    description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
  },
  {
    name: 'Test 2',
    age: 11,
    average: 8.2,
    score: '2-1',
    approved: true,
    description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
  },
  {
    name: 'Test 4',
    age: 10,
    average: 8.2,
    score: '3-1',
    approved: true,
    description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
  },
];

 
  const options = { 
    fieldSeparator: ',',
    quoteStrings: '"',
    decimalSeparator: '.',
    showLabels: true, 
    showTitle: true,
    title: 'My Awesome CSV',
    useTextFile: false,
    useBom: true,
    useKeysAsHeaders: true,
    // headers: ['Column 1', 'Column 2', etc...] <-- Won't work with useKeysAsHeaders present!
  };
 
const csvExporter = new ExportToCsv(options);
 
csvExporter.generateCsv(data);
```

---

Angular: Issue while exporting to CSV, field with '-' value converting to date
Problem is when export to csv score('3-1','2-1',..) values converted to date like (01-Mar,01-Feb,...). How to solve this issue. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Open the csv file using a text editor like Notepad and verify the dash content is correct.

When you say it converts them to dates, I'm assuming you're using Excel to open the csv file? If that is the case try selecting all values and changing the formatting to Text to see real values. Excel automatic formatting is most likely the issue and not the file itself.

CSV, or comma separated value, refers to formatting only.

Comment: Yes, I checked dash content is correct. can we do formatting to text for dash content field   explicitly using angular code. so that it will not convert to date format.

Comment: It looks like `score` is a string type. Trying storing it with an escaped `'` in front (ex. `'\'3-1'`. However, this may mess up your importing if you're not expecting that first character. The single quote forces Excel to display the content as Text